# Formatting different date formats to their locale compatible format

Tags: javascript, momentjs, date-fns

While stashing all the moment instances with date-fns, I came across one instance which actually says something like:

```
moment(userOnline).format('DD-MMM-YY | HH:mm')
```

I have created a small utility function which sorts of convert a date or date string into toLocaleDateString.

```
export const formatDisplayDate = (date, options = undefined) => {
  if (!(date instanceof Date)) {
    date = new Date(date);
    if (date === 'Invalid Date') {
      throw new Error('Parameter must be a date');
    }
  }
  let primeLocale = '';
  const locales = getBrowserLocales();
  if (Array.isArray(locales) && locales.length) {
    primeLocale = locales[0];
  }
  return date.toLocaleDateString(primeLocale, options);
};
```

However the toLocaleDateString() only returns a date in 'MM/DD/YYYY'. I want to format the dates with various formats to their locale formats and want to preserve the format passed to it. Other formats I have include - `'Do-MMM-YYYY HH:mm A', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss'`

Comment: `toLocaleString()` ?

Comment: What about that | in between those dates? @Bravo

Comment: Oh, right, you want to use native Date methods to create output like momentjs can do? Why not just use momentjs and be done with it? there's also `toLocaleTimeString` so you could get the date part and the time part and add `|` between them

Comment: also see: [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) which gives you full control of which and how each element of the date/time is formatted.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm looking at @pilchard